# Libreoffice Mendeley Plugin stopped merging citations

Tags: libreoffice, mendeley

After a number of successful merges, `Mendeley plugin for Libreoffice` does not merge citations anymore. The document I am working on it **has almost 100 citations**. How can I make it to work as before?

**Specifications:**

- OS: `14.04`
- Libreoffice version: `4.2.8.2` (Latest available via Ubuntu Repository)
- Mendeley version: `1.15.2` (Latest available via Ubuntu Repository)